# Can I get all functions in a script file, using bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

If I have a file:
dome.sh

```
$ls -l dome.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 0 Aug  8 11:19 dome.sh
```

and the contents of the file are similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash
function() {
    'work'
    }
another() {
    'different work'
    }
...
#30 functions later
yetANOTHERfunction () {
    'even more work'
    }
```

where "#30 functions later" means that there are 30 unique additional functions

Can I somehow itterate through all functions in this script to identify them?

something like:

```
for i in $(get all functions in this file); do
    echo $i
done
```

to produce:

```
function
another
...
yetANOTHERfunction
```

Comment: Should we assume that the file contains function definitions *only,* and no main-line code?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: P.S. `function` is a keyword in the shell, so it’s not a valid example *function **name**.* (I like to use things like `function1`, `function2`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

If you capitalize the "F" in "declare -F" then it will return lines like "declare -f functionName". Now all you need to do is trim off the first part of that line. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function () {
   return
}
another () {
   return
}
yetANOTHERfunction () {
   return
}
IFS=$'\n'
for f in $(declare -F); do
   echo "${f:11}"
done
```

Comment: Or just pipe to `cut` like this: `declare -F | cut -d ' ' -f3`.

Comment: ``function`` is a keyword in the shell, so it’s not a valid example *function name.*

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
get_fcn_list () {
    env -i bash --noprofile --norc -c '
    source "'"$1"'"
    typeset -f |
    grep '\''^[^{} ].* () $'\'' |
    awk "{print \$1}" |
    while read -r fcn_name; do
        type "$fcn_name" | head -n 1 | grep -q "is a function$" || continue
        echo "$fcn_name"
    done
'
}

for fcn_name in $(get_fcn_list dome.sh); do
    echo "$fcn_name"
done
```

Explanation:

- Rather than parsing the functions yourself, let `bash` parse them (with `source`) and dump the contents (`typeset -f`).
- The invocation `env -i bash --noprofile --norc` is meant to prevent `bash` from reading any initialization files. Otherwise, you might get functions defined in, e.g., `~/.bashrc`.
- `typeset -f` will dump all functions, and their definitions. Each definition starts with: *function name*, *space*, `()`, *space*, *newline*. `grep` and `awk` extract the function names from these lines.
- The reason for the filter is that you might get false positives when you have functions such as:

  ```
  f () 
  { 
      echo "
  a () 
  "
  }
  ```

  Here, the `while` loop would erroneously print `a`, but the filter takes care of that.
- Edited to print functions from file, and avoid including startup files.

Comment: thanks for this answer. I might need a day or two to get back on this project, but I will check this out and mark it as the answer.

Comment: To simplify things, you can call the builtin `declare -f` with no other arguments inside the script of interest to get a list of the function definitions in it. In other words, if you added the line declare -f to the bottom of a script and sourced it from a shell, it would output the function definitions, in that script only, to the terminal. It outputs the function name as well as body, so if you want just the name you'll have to pipe that output through sed / grep.. In a real application you would likely want the function list selectively based on criteria of your choosing (i.e. argument).

Comment: 1) `declare` and `typeset` are the same command. 2) All the functions from your shell (not necessarily from the file of interest) would appear in the output. This is the second point above.

Comment: I guess you are assuming that the file contains function definitions *only,* and no main-line code.  If you ***don’t*** make that assumption, and you aren’t very familiar with what the script does, then this answer is dangerous, because it runs the code.  It could modify file(s) (or delete them).  It could try to read input, in which case your ``get_fcn_list`` would hang, and you wouldn’t know why.  And, if it does an `exit`, then your subshell will terminate before it ever gets to the `typeset -f`, and you won’t get any output.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the solutions proposed here, but both had flaws:

- I have seen [bashBedlam's solution](https://superuser.com/a/1117642/1702641) in several answers to similar questions (for example [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/260656)) but, despite their popularity, they are all invariably WRONG, since simple calls to `declare -F` (or equivalent) DO NOT list the functions specifically declared in a script file, they also list exported functions from parent shell! *A clean environment is needed to prevent external declarations from interfering*.
- [Matei David's solution](https://superuser.com/a/1111244/1702641) takes environment side effects into account (very good), but is unnecessarily convoluted (why filtering the whole function definitions output by `typeset -f` when `declare -F` provides JUST those names?); besides that, it doesn't guard its output from possible stdout by sourced script.

Here it is my solution (credits to Matei David for `env/bash call`):

```
get_fcn_list () {
  env -i bash --noprofile --norc -c '
    source "'"$1"'" >/dev/null
    while read -r line; do
      echo ${line##* }
    done < <(declare -F)
    '
}

for fcn_name in $(get_fcn_list dome.sh); do
    echo "$fcn_name"
done
```

Comment: (1) We prefer normal sentence capitalization.  Use of all-capitals is generally perceived to be shouting.  So it’s somewhat rude to yell the word “wrong”, especially when the problem is such an edge case.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (2) If you assume that the file contains function definitions *only,* and no main-line code, then the `> /dev/null` is probably unnecessary.  If you ***don’t*** make that assumption, and you aren’t very familiar with what the script does, then this answer is dangerous, because it runs the code.  It could modify file(s) (or delete them).  It could try to read input, in which case your ``get_fcn_list`` would hang, and you wouldn’t know why.  And, if it does an `exit`, then your subshell will terminate before it even gets to the ``declare -F``, and you won’t get any output.

Comment: This still isn't limited to the functions declared in the specific script. If your script is sourcing other files, for example, you will also report any functions defined there, so I fear your answer suffers from the same limitation as the others.